# Python 3 change turtle pen brightness

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, noise, python-turtle

I am trying to generate random noise, and draw it on the screen, but I need the turtle's pen to be able to change the brightness

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is probably varying your color between white (or whatever background you are using) and the "brightest" you want to display. For example, if you want your bright color to be green, your RGB color code would be (0,255,0). The RGB color code for white is (255,255,255). So to vary "brightness", you would simultaneously change the red and blue channels between 0 for as bright as possible and 255 for as dim as possible.

If you want say 100 levels of brightness, you can use the `linspace` function from `numpy` (https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linspace.html) to get an array of values that are equally spaced out.

```py
import numpy as np
color_range = np.linspace(255, 0, 100)
# color_range will be a np array of length 100 where color_range[0] = 255.0 
# and color_range[99] = 0.0

# now we can create a list of colors from least bright to most bright
colors = [(int(i),255,int(i)) for i in color_range] 
# colors[0] will be (255, 255, 255) which is white
# colors[99] will be (0, 255, 0) which is green
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `colorsys` library to convert between a color model that supports brightness, we'll use HSV below, and the RGB colors that turtle uses.  Here's a gradient example:

```
from colorsys import hsv_to_rgb
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

WIDTH, HEIGHT = 100, 100
CURSOR_SIZE = 20

screen = Screen()
screen.setup(WIDTH, HEIGHT)
screen.setworldcoordinates(0, HEIGHT, WIDTH, 0)
screen.tracer(False)

turtle = Turtle()
turtle.hideturtle()
turtle.shape('square')
turtle.shapesize(1 / CURSOR_SIZE)
turtle.penup()

for y in range(HEIGHT):
    turtle.goto(0, y)

    for x in range(WIDTH):
        value = x * y / (WIDTH * HEIGHT)
        rgb = hsv_to_rgb(0.0, 1.0, value)
        turtle.color(rgb)
        turtle.stamp()
        turtle.forward(1)

screen.update()
screen.exitonclick()
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

where all the colors are different brightnesses of red.  To generate noise, we can import the `random()` function from the **random** library, and change the `value` assignment to:

```
value = random()
```

**(ENLARGED) OUTPUT**

[image]

Comment: When I try to implement your code, it gives me this error:                   
NotImplementedError: colorsys is not yet implemented in Skulpt on line 1 in main.py

Comment: @JacobMorrison, since Skulpt doesn't include the library colorsys.py, you can go to  [its source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.9/Lib/colorsys.py) and copy the definition of the `hsv_to_rgb()` function into your own code as it is completely self-contained.  And remove the `import`.